# « Offspring » en français

Tags: traduction, anglais

> Tom's sister came over on Saturday with all her *offspring*.

Quel mot ou expression rend le mot « offspring »

dans le sens de

> [humorous or formal] a person's children:
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/offspring

*Petits*, *progéniture*, *rejetons*,...?

**EDIT** (merci @Luke Sawczak)

To clarify the connotations for non-Anglophones and help search for equivalents: the word is normally associated with zoology, hence the humorous side is by comparison with "her young" or "her whelps" or "her issue"; on the other hand, it also appears in traditional translations of the Bible, e.g. in promises that Abraham's "offspring" (nowadays "descendants") will be numerous. In the example given, of course, the formality is misplaced and so also humorous :)

Comment: @Luke Sawczak : Merci pour l'édit:-)!

Comment: Pas de quoi. To clarify the connotations for non-Anglophone answerers and help search for equivalents: the word is normally associated with zoology, hence the humorous side is by comparison with "her young" or "her whelps" or "her issue"; on the other hand, it also appears in traditional translations of the Bible, e.g. in promises that Abraham's "offspring" (nowadays "descendants") will be numerous. In the example given, of course, the formality is misplaced and so also humorous :)

Comment: p.s. valider _marmaille_ vs. rejetons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'humour contenu dans « offspring » tel qu'appliqué à des enfants d'être humains est d'habitude capturé entièrement par le terme français « **progéniture** », lequel, autrement, n'est utilisé sans connotations que dans un contexte très formel ; il n'est pas nécessaire qu'il existe un contexte particulier pour que le ton ironique mais pas réellement méprisant et plutôt badin soit compris. L'ironie peut d'ailleurs être toute relative, due par exemple seulement au nombre anormalement grand des fils et filles, ou elle peut être mieux fondée et due au comportement inhabituel des enfants (par exemple sans cesse chamailleurs), lesquels, de plus, peuvent n'être qu'au nombre d'un seul.

> (TLFi) 2. Fam., souvent p.plaisant. ou p.iron. [Par rapport au père de famille, ou à la mère, ou aux parents] Enfants. Synon. (petite) famille.

- Samedi la sœur de Tom, avec toute sa progéniture, est venue nous voir.  (*plutôt écrit que parlé*)
- La sœur de Tom est venue nous voir samedi, avec toute sa progéniture. (*parlé ou écrit*)

Le ton n'est pas ironique dans la phrase suivante et le terme a une connotation de famille nombreuse;

- Toute sa petite famille lui cause bien des tracas ; elle n'en fini pas de contenter les uns, punir les autres et finalement de faire le gendarme parmi eux.

Il est méprisant dans la phrase ci-après.

- Nous en avons par dessus la tête d'elle et de toute sa petite famille, qui se croient chez eux dès qu'ils arrivent et qui s'imaginent que l'on doivent être à leurs petits soins.

« Petit » a bien été utilisé dans la littérature de façon plus ou moins neutre par le passé, mais de nos jours il a des connotations populaires, voire très populaires, et nombreux sont ceux qui le considère comme un terme à n'appliquer qu'à la progéniture des animaux ; il est à éviter selon mon point de vue.

Comment: Je commente un peu tard mais selon moi le "petite famille" est seulement méprisant dans le second exemple parce que le ton de la phrase est plutôt négatif...

Comment: @LaurentS. Je ne suis pas absolument sûr de ce que j'avance maintenant que je dois réexaminer la chose, mais voyez quand même [ceci](https://www.rtl.fr/actu/insolite/toute-sa-petite-famille-dans-une-ferrari-458-spider-7762394842).

Answer (score 6):

Ces phrases ont les mêmes significations:

- Tom's sister came over on Saturday with all her offspring.
- La sœur de Tom est passée samedi avec tous ses enfants. *(neutre)*
- La sœur de Tom est passée samedi avec tous ses rejetons. *(ton légèrement familier et péjoratif)*
- La sœur de Tom est passée samedi avec tous ses petits. *(ton légèrement familier et affectif)*

Answer (score 0):

C'est « progéniture » en français. Je suis d'accord avec le commentaire de LPH.
Super groupe de rock, soit dit en passant.